# How to write a shell pipeline to print the group owner of all sub files a directory?

Tags: command-line, files, find, ownership

I need to know the group owner of the files in a specific directory, including the files in its subdirectories.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a shell pipeline for this - the `find` command's `-printf` action can output the group information:

```
  %g     File's group name, or numeric group ID if the group has no name.
```

Add `%p` if you want the filename as well:

```
find path/to/dir/ -type f -printf '%g %p\n'
```

---

Same thing, but using the external `stat` command:

```
find path/to/dir/ -type f -exec stat -c '%G %n' {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `find` [as in @steeldriver's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1284591/618353) is the best solution, but if you absolutely have to use pipes you can use the following command:

```bash
ls -l -R /path/to/dir | grep ^- | awk '{print $4}'
```

- `-l` tells `ls` to use long listing format and `-R` lists all subdirectories inside `/path/to/dir`.
- Then the output is piped to `grep` so we select files only by matching only the lines that start with `-` (`^-`).
- Finally, the output is piped to `awk` and we only print the fourth field (`$4`), which is the group field.

If you also need to print the filenames, you can use the following command:

```bash
ls -l -R /path/to/dir | grep ^- | awk '{$1=$2=$3=$5=$6=$7=$8=""; print $0}'
```

Comment: Does this way include the sub files too?

Comment: Yes. That's what the `-R` flag does.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a pre-fab command.

`sudo apt-get install tree`

`tree -g /the/directory`

[image]

Other useful options in the man pages `man tree`.